# How to set newRecordStoragePid for TYPO3 extension modules?

Tags: model-view-controller, typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

How can I set newRecordStoragePid for TYPO3 extension modules (BE part of the extension)? I've tried the following setting:

```
module.tx_dscontrolpanel_web_dscontrolpaneldscontrolpanel {
persistence {
    storagePid = 0
    classes {
        DS\Dscontrolpanel\Domain\Model\Entitymodulelist{
            newRecordStoragePid = 0
        }
    }
}
view {
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:dscontrolpanel/Resources/Private/Templates/
    partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:dscontrolpanel/Resources/Private/Partials/
    layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:dscontrolpanel/Resources/Private/Layouts/
}
```

But it only takes the pid of the chosen page in the page tree. Is this setting even available for the BE? Is there a diffrent 'clean' way to set the pid for new objects in TYPO3 backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgot to include the static template of my extension. Now everything works as expected.